# Reading properties file value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have gone through a few replies about using `$http` service for accessing the properties file, but now sure how it would fit in this scenario
I have created a service that returns the hostnames from the poperties file, the calling client to this service should make a blocking call to the service and proceed only if the property file is read.

```
var serviceMod = angular.module('serviceModule',[])
.factory('configService', function($http){
    return {
        getValue: function(key){
            $http.get("js/resources/urls.properties").success(function(response){

                console.log('how to send this response to clients sync??? ' + response)

            })
            return ????

        }
    }
})
```

someOtherControllr.js

```
var urlValue = configService.getValue('url')
```

The problem I am facing is to do with the aync nature of the `$http` service. By the time the response is received by the callback, the main thread is already finished executing the `someOtherController.js`

Comment: was my suggestion able to help you in any way? Please share your findings

Answer (score 2):

You need to resolve the promise returned by the service. We can just return the `$http` call and resolve it in our controller (since `return $http.get` be a promise itself). Check out the AngularJS [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs for a bettering understanding of the underlying mechanics going on, and observe the following change...

```
.factory('configService', function($http) {
    return {
        getValue: function(key) {
            return $http.get('js/resources/urls.properties');
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
var urlValue;

// --asynchronous
configService.getValue('url').then(function(response) {
    urlValue = response.data; // -- success logic
});

console.log('be mindful - I will execute before you get a response');
[...]
```

Comment: so each time we need to access the url in the calling userController.js, I have to write the client code in the response block?

Comment: Hm, is that just static data? Why not either make a `constant` or place it on `$rootScope` in your app `.run` block? Can you explain a bit more what you are needing this for, how often, and if it changes?

Comment: also, are you using ui-router by chance?

Comment: It can't be a constant because it I am not supposed to touch or modify the js file as these values can change by the other non-tech people.

Comment: then this should work. What are your specific concerns? Also no need to make this sync, it's generally never a good Idea. What will not work with async in this situation?

Comment: My concern is that if the client makes a call to the service, the the service must return before the client can execute the next statement. So, as per your example the console.log() statement might get executed before the response. To avoid this, the client need to write its implementation within the callback function, each time it needs to read the properties file, which is messy.

Comment: It's what you'll need to do, though. That's how this works

Comment: perform logic on success, not terribly messy if you crate reusable functions, or something

Comment: hey, have you made any progress on this? Was my suggestion able to point you in the right direction?

Comment: @tintin will you please share some feedback on this? Did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way - use callback (it will still be async. In fact you cant make it sync) :

```
    getValue: function(key, onSuccess){
        $http.get("js/resources/urls.properties").success(function(response){
            onSuccess(response);
   })
```